# Unix: check if file is folder

Tags: bash

So I need to loop through a tree of directories, currently I can print off all the files in a directory, but once that is done I need to be able to go into the subfolders of the starting directory and so on. My Program prints off the files and the folders as a start, but I need to check each one to make sure it is a directory and then enter it. Could someone provide some guidance on this?

Answer (score 13):

`help test` yields

> test: test [expr]
>
> [...]
>
> -d FILE        True if file is a directory.
>
> [...]
>
> Exit Status:
>   Returns success if EXPR evaluates to true; fails if EXPR evaluates to false or an invalid argument is given.

`test` can be abbreviated with `[`, so you can do

```
if [ -d "$file" ]; then
    # do stuff
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

```
test -d myFileOrFolder
```

but what you describe looks like the behaviour of `find`.

Answer (score 1):

From comments entered to some of the responses I am guessing you want to run some script in each of the directory. In that case one of the possible ways is to use `find` with `exec` options as follow:

```
find ./ -type d -exec sh -c "cd {} && <your_script_with_absolute_path>" \;
```

For example, in the current dir there is a script `test.sh` & you want to execute it in each of the subdir in the current dir then

```
find ./ -type d -exec sh -c "cd {} && `pwd`/test.sh" \;
```

To the `find` command `-type d` will ask to look for all directories in path `./` passed as first argument. `-exec` will execute command for each such find, in this case `sh -c` which is creating a shell & executing a command with quotes, `{}` indicates the argument found by `find` command.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-d` operator to test for the existence of a directory:

```
if [ -d "$DIR" ]; then
    ...
fi
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, then how would I enter that directory and run the script again?

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
[ -d your_filename ] && it's a folder ...
```

Comment: then how would i enter the new directory and then call my script again?

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type d
```

this finds all subdirectories

Comment: then how would i enter the new directory and then call my script again?

Comment: there's an `-execdir` option and a few others, depending on your version of `find`.  You could also just pipe this to a while loop which explicitly visited each directory.

Answer (score 0):

Based on some of the comments, I'm guessing that you don't actually want to print the directories, but rather process all of the regular files in a directory tree (including all of the subdirectories).  If that's the case, you may want to take a look at the `exec` option to find.

From memory, you probably want something like this (using the `cat` command to stand in for your script):

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} \;
```

In this example, all of the *non-directory* files in the entire tree (recursively) will be processed by `cat` (printed to standard out).